# How to retrieve the text between two html markup with c#?

Tags: c#, html, regex

How to retrieve the text between two html markup with c# ?

Edit : This is the only purpose of my question, "how to retrieve the string within two html markup using c#", that's all.

Comment: Could you be a little more precise?

Comment: got no clue what you are asking, so yeah, more precise wil come in handy

Comment: sorry but ... lol, maybe the question is too simple and you don't understand what i really want.
The response : the question is precise, the purpose is to retrieve a string within two html markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to obtaining the text within a tag, you can either use a HTML parsing framework such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) or you can use a regular expression. Something like:

```
(?<=\<title\>).+?(?=\<\/title\>)
```

The above will only match the text within the title tag.

**Edit:** You really should update your question to better explain what you are trying to achieve. The members of SO are more than happy to help, but if they can't determine what you want they will likely move on to someone else's question.

Comment: The backslashes are not necessary.

Comment: ...and in some regex flavors (not C#), \< means "start of word" and \> means "end of word".